# Json.Net - How to serialize a C# List without the outer brackets?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the SendGrid Api and apparently their API does not like an array of email messages to be passed in. It wants an array of objects without the outer brackets.

In their example 
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

You can see that the result of serializing a collection results in a Json Array of objects which makes perfect sense. But is there a way to omit the outer brackets or will I just have to parse them out of the string manually? I'd rather avoid parsing if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Arrays must have brackets.  Don't do that.

Comment: Can you link to the SendGrid API doc that mentions this? Also, a *valid* JSON array has to have the brackets. As for your problem you can do it with a simple trim by specifying the `[` and `]` as the chars to be trimmed.

Comment: You could serialize each collection entry individually.  Do you also need a comma separator, as in "comma separated JSON"?  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11950248

Comment: After further testing, I think I completely misunderstood their API. This link shows the example of send a mail message but I think the API doesn't allow multiple messages. You might have to send multiple Personalization objects in ONE mail message. I feel a bit stupid now. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html  The reason why I thought it doesn't want the outer brackets is because testing via POSTMAN it errord with the brackets but didn't without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a serializer that does that because the behavior you're describing isn't valid JSON (see the format specification at http://www.json.org/), so *by definition* a correctly-implemented serializer won't do this. It's a little unclear to me exactly why you'd want to do this in the first place and I don't recommend doing it but if you must you can always manually strip out the brackets using a regex or something.